# Why my plot change after adding scale_y_continuous(limits =c(0,500) inside my code? I mean the number changed

Tags: r, ggplot2

Origin

```
q4Data %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(stat="summary",fun=mean) + 
  aes(sex , time, group = sex , fill=sex ) +
  ggtitle("Mean time by Group")+
  geom_text(stat="summary",fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)+
  aes(label=round(..y..,2),vjust=-0.5)+
  xlab("group") + ylab("time") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J2YY.png)
after

```
q4Data %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(stat="summary",fun=mean) + 
  aes(sex , time, group = sex , fill=sex ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits =c(0,500))+
  ggtitle("Mean time by Group")+
  geom_text(stat="summary",fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)+
  aes(label=round(..y..,2),vjust=-0.5)+
  xlab("group") + ylab("time") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J7Vs.png)
can anyone tell me how to fix it?

I tried to remove that line, and everything is fine however whenever I tried to est the limit of y axis it broken.

Comment: Presumably some of your data points fall outside the range 0-500, so removing them changes the mean (which is calculated only on the surviving data points).  Try using `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,500))` instead.

Comment: `scale_y_continuous(limits =c(0,500))` will exclude observations > 500 from the mean calculation. You'll want to use `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,500))` to adjust the limits without affecting the calculation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.